# Python class property and class constants

Tags: python

I'm trying to work with "getters" and "setters" in python classes. I have a simple Rectangle class defined below where each Rectangle object has the class variables length and width defined. There is a class constant called sides which knows about the number of sides of this particular shape. Now, when I run this class, everything works just fine. I can do something like

```
>>> rect = Rectangle(2,3)
>>> rect.length
2
>>> rect.width
3
```

However, if I try to have it print out the class constant sides, it simply returns this

```
>>> rect.sides
<property object at 0x037F6C90>
```

rather than returning the value 4. How can I get it to return the value? On a potentially related note, I tried having the property method for the sides variable defined as such

```
@property
def sides(self):
    return self._sides
```

This works for the other object variables, but when I attempt to access sides through this method, I get an error saying Rectangle has no attribute _sides. Is the reference to sides with `self.__class__.sides` proper?

### Rectangle class

```
import abc
from Shape import Shape

class Rectangle(Shape):

    sides = 4

    def __init__(self, length, width):
        super().__init__('Rectangle')
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    #The getters
    @property
    def sides(self):
        return self.__class__.sides

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._width

    #The setters

    @sides.setter
    def sides(self, value):
        if value != 4:
            raise ValueError('Error: Cannot set number of sides to be a value '
                             'other than 4.')
        self._sides = value

    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError('Error: Length must be positive.')
        self._length = value

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError('Error: Width must be positive.')
        self._width = value



    def getArea(self):
        return self.length * self.width
```

Comment: You have to *call* the method `rect.sides()`

Comment: `sides` is a method (therefore callable), `width` and `length` are actually instance members (as declared in your `__init__`).

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense. I don't have to do that with the length or width properties. I can simply do rect.length which automatically calls the property method defined above. Why should it be different with sides?

Comment: @Lukasz R. So are you saying I cannot write an actual method with the property decorator for class constants like I can for instance members?

Comment: there seems to be quite a bit of confusion i the code about using attributes with and without the `_` prefix.

Comment: Also, please note you do not need to explicitly go through `__class__` in order to reach a class attribute.

Comment: Would you care to enlighten me regarding the `_` prefix? Every example I've found has used that and my code did not work without it.

Comment: Without underscores you have conflicts in rectangle instance namespace. Both method (property decorated method) and member are named the same. Probably method replaces member (as it's declared after a member).

Comment: So why does it not work that way for instance variables? I don't see the differentiation.

Comment: @zephyr Hint: add print statements 'property called' to width and length properties. You'll see they are not called at all. Also, I fix previous statement - int literals passed though constructor replaces getters. Not other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this -

```
#The getters
@property
def sides(self):
    return self.__class__._sides
```

Instead of -

```
#The getters
@property
def sides(self):
    return self.__class__.sides
```

Notice the `_sides`

Also, at the start of the class I think you wanted to initialize `_sides` instead of `sides`.

You need to use a different name than `sides` because `sides` is used to refer to the class property, so if you try to `return self.__class__.sides` it will directly return the `property` object, you can use `type(rect.sides)` in your example , where it does not work, to check what its type is.

Also, to note, instead of `self.__class__.sides` , if you return `self.sides` , inside your `getter` function, it would keep on recursively calling the getter function causing python to error out with -

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: `sides` is not a method, it's a property.

Comment: Doing this results in the statement. '`TypeError: 'property' object is not callable`

Comment: Okay, that works, but then why can't I just use the name `sides` throughout. Why append the `_` in both cases? My understanding was that that simply makes the variable "private".

Comment: Please check latest answer, fixed it.

Comment: To make a variable private you have to prepend double underscore.
You do not need to use `_sides` itself, but you need to use a different name than `sides` because `sides` is used to refer to the class property, so if you try to return `self.__class__.sides` it will diretly return the `property` object, you can use type(rect.sides) in your example , where it does not work, to check what its type is

Comment: Not even prepending double underscores makes a variable fully private. It can still be directly accessed with `instancename._ClassName__varname`.

Comment: there are no private variables in python, just convention https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Rectangle.sides as side is a class property and common to any instantiated object

Comment: sides could be a property of the class, or a function of an object. If you are calling a function, add ()

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem because I still get back the property object, not the value of sides. What's more, why shouldn't an object of a class know about it's own constants? I don't see a reason why the object can't access the variable while the class can.